# How do I put a conditioned count of a joined table in a separate column of the same joined table

Tags: mysql

Lets say, I have two tables - `people` and `bonus`

```
------------
people
------------
people_id | company_id  | job_id
  1       |     1       |    2
  2       |     1       |    4
  3       |     2       |    1
  4       |     2       |    3
  5       |     3       |    5

------------
bonus
------------
job_id    | bonus_id 
  1       |     101    
  2       |     102    
  3       |     103
```

Now, I want to have a joined table like the following

```
-------------
JOINED TABLE 
-------------
people_id | company_id  | job_id | bonus_id | no_of_bonus_for_company
  1       |     1       |    2   |   102    |      1
  2       |     1       |    4   |   NULL   |      1
  3       |     2       |    1   |   101    |      2
  4       |     2       |    3   |   103    |      2
  5       |     3       |    5   |   NULL   |      0
```

I need to have the main search term in `people_id` as in -

```
SELECT p.people_id,
       p.company_id,
       p.job_id,
       b.bonus_id
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN bonus b
     ON p.job_id = b.job_id
WHERE p.people_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY p.people_id ASC;
```

But how do I get the fifth column of the joined table? It actually counts the no. of bonus id's for each company id in the joined table itself.

Comment: can you use sqlfiddle? it will be easier to help you

Comment: Here you go - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63dbc/1/0

Comment: I don't get where the `no_of_bonus_for_company` value is coming from?

Comment: `no_of_bonus_for_company` is the sum of occurrences of `bonus_id` for each `company_id`.

For example, `company_id` 1 appears 2 times - one has a `bonus_id` 102, and the other is `NULL` - which sums up to 1. `company_id` 2 appears 2 times - one has a `bonus_id` 101, and the other is 103 - which sums to 2. `company_id` 3 appears once, with a `bonus_id` `NULL` so that the value of `no_of_bonus_for_company` is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that you are telling us part of the picture so I will reserve judgement about the DB schema, normalization etc.

Given the presented facts you can retrieve the information in the following manner.

**NOTE** : This is TSQL syntax but I don't think that the mySQL syntax should be very different i.e. ISNULL -> IFNULL

```
   SELECT p.people_id
        , p.company_id
        , p.job_id
        , b.bonus_id
        , ISNULL((
                   SELECT COUNT(pt.Job_Id)
                     FROM Bonus bt 
               INNER JOIN People pt
                       ON pt.job_Id = bt.job_Id
                    WHERE pt.company_Id = p.company_Id
                 GROUP BY pt.company_Id                 
                 ), 0) AS no_of_bonus_for_company
     FROM People p 
LEFT JOIN Bonus b
       ON p.job_Id = b.job_Id
```